# why texturing in blender dosn't work in all partes?

Tags: blender, blender-2.76

[why don't work texturing in all parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2p90.png)

```
   'how to make texture for allll the character'[enter image description here][why don't work texturing in all parts][1]
```

[only this part in photo is i can texturing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5eJL.png)

Answer (score 0):

By what I can see in the image, it seems that the character is divided in different objects.

If it is so, you have two options:

1. Join all the objects.
2. Make all the objects have the same material, and unwrap them.